# how to use ur friendly / slug properly in rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-url

i have a table which i generated with scaffold,
something like this

> rails generate scaffold Book title:string year:integer etc...

only admin can access above table with url something like :

> admin/books/book-1
>   admin/books/book-2

i use friendlyid gem to generate slug value, and i don't have problem with that.

but now i need to access a page in public and query book data based on slug string, i really have no idea how to make route accept an url like this :

```
public/book-1
```

currently i do it with query string : `public?book_id=123` 
and get the parameters like this : `Book.where(:id=>params[book_id])`
and i need to change it with slug way?

i tried to add this to my route file, but still no luck

```
# get 'public/:slug', to: 'public#detailed_book', as: 'slugged_post'
```

please advice, kindly show me how to setup my route file correctly and how to get the parameter in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the record using

```
Book.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thx, but can  you show how to setup my route file to accept an url something like this "public/book-1" instead of "public?book_id = 1"

Comment: What is the current route

Comment: get 'book' => 'public#detailed_book'

Comment: Can you paste an example url for public controller that you are using currently?

This should work `get 'public/:slug', to: 'public#detailed_book'`

Comment: Then you can access it using `params[:slug]` in the action